# 1 month Timer for Premium Membership

Tags: php, timer, membership

I have a site with premium memberships, but PHP script is not working well..

I the table accounts I have a column called reset_timer(default value is 0). When someone purchase a new premium membership, PHP add with time(); function into the reset_timer.

Premium is 1 month yes and is working well, but the "countdown" script is not working, the script take only the first reset_timer value so for example if the user1 purchase premium membership today, after 5 days, he have 25 days left, but if somebody in another account purchase 1 month of premium, he have 25 days left too, because script only taking the first reset_timer value.. This is the code:

```
function time_reset()
{
    $now = time();
    DB::select('accounts');
    $timer = DB::fetch_row();   
    $timer = $timer['reset_timer'];
    $difference = ($now - $timer);
    return (2629743 - $difference);
}
```

How I can do it for the script look in every account and reset timer for work correctly?

Thank you very much!

Comment: It always fetches the first member row. What Database (Wrapper) are you using? Basically you will need to add a WHERE constraint for the current member. impossible to say more without knowing your datastructures.

Comment: My 'accounts' table structure is this:
http://i44.tinypic.com/nmwylv.png 
Thanks!

Comment: Please help! I need this urgently! THnx

Comment: you will need to select the user account that corresponds to the current user, it is impossible to say how to do this without knowing what DB class you are using etc.

Comment: Hello thx mightyuhu! but my table estructure is this:
http://i.stack.imgur.com/x7vhb.png